# How do I make my Docker image of MERN stack application using ubuntu:20.04 as a base image of my container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, devops

Greeting from my side....
I am very new to the docker. And I just learn the basics of docker like : containers , images, volumes, docker-compose. So I have one task that I need to dockerise my MERN stack app i.e. Mongodb, Express, React, Node. But the condition is that I used operating system as ubuntu:20.04 version. Now I need to dockerise my MERN app and the base image of my docker image file is ubuntu:20.04. How can I do that ?
Like I am trying like this :

```
FROM node:16-ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /app/
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

When I try to build it it gives me an error :

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "node:16-ubuntu:20.04": invalid reference format
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

Can anyone can solve my problem ? or guide me for the same.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing ? TO implement this you will need to use the desired base image then copy your artifacts , installed the required dependencies and then use CMD execute instructions when your container starts. are u facing any errors while building this docker image?

Comment: No I did not build yet just am I asking that is it right or note which I have written in my Dockerfile ?

Comment: I have seen this error :  "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "node:16-ubuntu:20.04": invalid reference format
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed"

Comment: From needs to be changed I don't think there is such a tag for a node image. Other than that it looks fine you have copied your code and then ran npm install. Then used cmd looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you have done is you are trying to pull a non existing docker image.You need not mention Ubuntu:20.04 in your base image try to find a base image in node 16.x

I could find this image and it should be fine and compatible in linux machines. Try using this base image

```
From node:16.3.0-alpine
```

If you need some other base image go to docker hub and search for node and in filter search node:16 base images.

[node docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/tags?page=1&name=16)

To build a react image try to follow some blogs to get an idea what all steps you need to do in the docker file

[Build a react image](https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/dockerize-react-app)

How I have built a react image

```
FROM node:16.3.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app/
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 7777
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Ensure that the port you expose and port you configure is the same. This could be found in web pack.config.js

```
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 7777
  },
```

Comment: I have one doubt like when we create a container then which os is installed in our container ?

Comment: And node-16-alpine what does it mean. it is something like node version which is compatible for linux os ?

Comment: @AbhishekPoddar it means that the node image is built on top of alpine not ubuntu. Both are linux based but alpine has a smaller size. When building apps, try to find the closest prebuilt images on docker hub

Comment: Abhisek I think you are missing a lot of basic concept in docker. Docker was created to fix issues of os. The node image which I gave would be compatible in linux. Try going through this : https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/ and https://medium.com/swlh/alpine-slim-stretch-buster-jessie-bullseye-bookworm-what-are-the-differences-in-docker-62171ed4531d

Comment: which node image is built on the top of the ubuntu:20.04 ? can you please give me the exact name thank you

Comment: Can you try to build the image with the base image which I gave ? It should work fine in Ubuntu:20.04 . Please read through the docker concepts or go through YouTube videos I feel you are missing a lot of concept.

Comment: Updated my answer I am able to run a simple react application by using this docker file(updated my answer). This should work in ubuntu system as well